# Submit form, close popup window and refresh parent page

Tags: javascript, php, html

### popup1.php

```
<script>
function pepz(pageURL, title,w,h) {
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 
</script>

<a href="" onclick="pepz('<?php echo"popup2.php"; ?>', 'myPop1',465,410)"><?php print"Click"; ?></a></td>
```

### popup2.php

```
<form action='#' method='post'>
<input type='submit'>
<form>
```

---

After clicking the submit button in a form in a popup, I need the popup to close and the parent page which called the popup to refresh.

What am i doing wrong? thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to add the following attribute to your submit button:

```
onClick="window.parent.location.reload();window.close()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your popup like this from your parent page:

```
window.open("foo.html","windowName", "width=400,height=400,scrollbars=no");
```

Submit your form using a function.  Control the window closing event and make it refresh parent page.

```
<form action='#' method='post' name='my_form'>
<input type="button" value="Upload"  onclick="closeSelf();"/>
</form>
<script>
  window.onunload = refreshParent;
  function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
  }
  function closeSelf(){
    document.forms['my_form'].submit();
    window.close();   
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Heya, I saw this answer and got curious. Why bother putting the reload functionality into a separate function that is triggered when the page closes (I assume that's what setting the function to the unload property of window does) ?
Why not put it between the form submission and closing the window?

Comment: I apologize, @PhilippDoerner, but I'm not sure that I have an answer for your doubt, since I coded this almost 4 yrs ago and can't recall in what context this code was (re)used.